# Change properties output package exams, R

Tags: r, latex, r-exams

I need to write questions with the exams package of R and Latex with numbering and without title, like this:

[image: I need so]

I don't need the title "Question", like this:

[image: I do not need that]

Last image was write with the following code, from:

http://www.r-exams.org/templates/switzerland/

The code in R is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
library("exams")
#exams2html("swisscapital.Rnw")
exams2pdf("swisscapital.Rnw")
@

\begin{question}[""]
What is the seat of the federal
authorities in Switzerland
(i.e., the de facto capital)?

\begin{answerlist}
  \item Basel
  \item Bern
  \item Geneva
  \item Lausanne
  \item Zurich
  \item St.~Gallen
  \item Vaduz
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
There is no de jure capital but
the de facto capital and seat of
the federal authorities is Bern.

\begin{answerlist}
  \item False.
  \item True.
  \item False.
  \item False.
  \item False.
  \item False.
  \item False.
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{Swiss Capital}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0100000}
\exshuffle{5}

\end{document}
```

It is possible to write questions with numbering and without title, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Define each question as an individual `.Rnw` file, then using a template, that you can customize later, you will get the questions listed. When each question has different number of points I think you could insert that information at the beginning of each question (inside the `.Rnw` file). For the simple case run the R script:

```
library("exams")

## exam with a simple vector of exercises in R/LaTeX (.Rnw) format
myexam2 <- c("swisscapital.Rnw","switzerland.Rnw")

## generate the PDF version of a exam with template exam.tex
exams2pdf(myexam2, template = "exam.tex")
```

[image: exams2pdf output]

For guidance on authoring LaTeX templates for the `exams` package, see also Section 3 in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`. Table 4 shows that the default `plain.tex` template defines the `{question}` environment with the `\textbf{Problem}` title whereas for example the `exam.tex` template above does not (and omits the solution). The files for these examples (questions and templates) can also be obtained as in the examples for the `exams_skeleton()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I will review the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Robert, I added some further pointers to the first `exams` vignette that explains the structure of the LaTeX templates.

Answer (score 1):

With `exams2pdf()` you can use your own `template` file to customize the appearance of your exam. See the answer by @Robert for details.

Additionally, you might be interested in using `exams2nops()` which provides a standardized format, mainly for single-choice and multiple-choice exercises, that can be automatically scanned and evaluated. This also allows for a few customization options that might be useful in your case. See http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/exams2nops/ for a tutorial with further details. For a quick impression, consider the example:

```
exams2nops("switzerland.Rnw",
  language = "es", points = 0.5, showpoints = TRUE,
  intro = "Responder las siguientes preguntas.")
```

[image: exams2nops, page 1] [image: exams2nops, page 3]